# about Bounded Operator

Tags: operator-theory

Let be $l_p$ ( $1 \le p \le \infty$ ) space of sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. How can I prove that operator $L(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(a_{1}x_{1},a_{2}x_{2},a_{3}x_{3},\ldots)$ is bounded if and only if sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$ is bounded ?

Comment: If $\|L(x)\|_p\leq A\|x\|_p$ for all $x\in ell_p$, then in particular $|a_n|=\|L(0,0,...,1,0,...)\|_p\leq A\|(0,0,...,1,0,...)\|_p=A$. Therefore, $a_n$ is bounded. Conversely, if $|a_n|\leq A$, then $\|L(x)\|_p\leq |A|\|x\|_p$. Therefore, $L$ is bounded.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)_n$ be bounded and $x = (x_1, x_2, ...)$.

$$\vert \vert L(x) \vert \vert_p^p = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \vert a_ix_i \vert ^p \leq \vert \vert (a_n)_n \vert \vert_\infty^p \vert \vert x \vert \vert_p^p$$so $L$ is bounded.

Let $L$ be bounded and $e_i = (0, ...0, 1, 0, ...)$ the unit vector with a $1$ in its i-th component.

$$\vert \vert L \vert \vert \geq \vert \vert L(e_i) \vert \vert_p = \vert a_i \vert$$

so $(a_n)_n$ is bounded by $\vert \vert L \vert \vert$.

Comment: Thank you 